# Automatically go back to origin ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I want the AddViewController to automatically close and go back to the tableViewController after post got pressed. It worked all the time before but since I changed the TableViewController to a normal ViewController with the tableView as a Subview it doesn't work anymore... Here's the code for my addVC

```
@IBOutlet weak var postButton: CustomizableButton!
@IBOutlet weak var postBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var jobTextView: RoundText!


@IBAction func postPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if jobTextView.text != "" {

        // Create and save a new job
        let newJob = Job(text: jobTextView.text)
        newJob.save()

                }
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = postBarButtonItem
    title = "What about your Job"

    jobTextView.text = ""
    jobTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How do you present the `AddViewController`?

If you present it modally, you can do `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` in your `postPressed`.

Otherwise, if it is in the navigation stack you can do `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`

Comment: geeez, thanks a lot bro haha my dumbass just forgot that these lines exist